In SPAKE2(+) is it safe for B to send the key confirmation first?
Both RFC 9382 (SPAKE2) and RFC 9383 (SPAKE2+) have language that seems to require 4 messages to complete the protocol.

In particular, A sends a key confirmation message cA to B, and B responds with its own key confirmation message cB.


In particular, the Verifier sends a key confirmation message, confirmV, to the Prover, which in turn responds with its own key confirmation message, confirmP.

From a data dependency perspective, it's not necessary for B to wait for A's key confirmation; as soon as it sends its first message it also has all the information required to send the key confirmation. This would eliminate one round trip from the protocol since it could bundle the key confirmation with B's share.
The question: in SPAKE2(+) if B/Verifier sends the key confirmation first, before receiving A's key confirmation, is there an issue? I certainly don't see it, yet the RFC's language seems designed to exclude this obvious optimization (yet without any explicit warning not to do it, either)

I noticed in SPAKE2+ (RFC 9383) the text contains

Note that shareV and confirmV MAY be sent in the same message.

Which directly answers my question.
Similar text does not appear in the SPAKE2 RFC. I contacted the author of RFC 9382, who confirmed this omission was an editorial oversight, and that bundling the key confirmation with the response is safe with SPAKE2 as well.
